# What is the problem with this Switch statement?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, switch-statement

This is the result am looking for.
but it gives me different result.

Gold Medal
Silver Medal
Bronze Medal
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  switch (i) {
    case 1:
      console.log("Gold Medal");

    case 2:
      console.log("Silver Medal");

    case 3:
      console.log("Bronze Medal");

    default:
      console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Missing break statements.

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

> and executes statements after the first case clause with a matching value, **until a break statement is encountered**

You have no `break` statements.